# How to pass a function in a render inside a column (problem with scope)

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm having a problem with scope, how can I access **showModal** function in my header? In this header I have a column called lastWinners which renders a button and in this button I want to show a modal when I press but I'm getting an typeError: Cannot read property 'showModal' of undefined.

```
export class EventsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  state = { visible: false };

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: true,
    });
  };

  handleOk = e => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    });
  };

  handleCancel = e => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { schema, loadEvents, match } = this.props
    return (
      <Card title='Eventos' bordered={false}>
        <DataTable
          dataLoader={loadEvents}
          header={header}
            
        />
        <Modal
          title="Basic Modal"
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onOk={this.handleOk}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
        ></Modal>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}

const header = {
  id: { title: 'ID' },
  winnersQuantity: { title: 'Quantidade de vencedores' },
  lastWinners: {
    title: 'Ganhadores',
    render: () => (
      <Button
        onClick={this.showModal} <--------- typeError: Cannot read property 'showModal' of undefined
      >
        <Icon type='trophy' />
      </Button>
    ),
  },
}
```

Comment: same error TypeError: Cannot read property 'showModal' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You will have to either bind the method to the class, or use an arrow function when passing it as a prop in order to have `this` correctly defined.

Bind the function

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
  }
```

or pass it inside arrow function

```
      <Button onClick={() => this.showModal()}>
        <Icon type='trophy' />
      </Button>
```